# How to either: wrap image in text or place image at specific location

Tags: xetex, positioning, wrapfigure, cv

I am very new to Latex and I am struggling to place a picture of me at the top of my resume.

I did my best to make a minimal working example since I have seen that it is appreciated while looking for the solution on to this problem on my own. However since I do not know much I left unnecessary things I am sure but I wanted to make sure whatever problem I have is left there.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, final]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=12.0}\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont\scshape{John Doe }} \hfill 1 of 2\\[2mm]

\raggedright
{\Large\so{{\Large\Letter} email@server.com}}\\[0.5mm]
{\large\so{{\Large\Telefon} (55) 55-5555-5555}}

\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth]{Foto}

\section{Education}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The first line of my resume is my name, then my email and phone number. So far I can place the picture after those 3 lines or in one of those lines. I want the picture to be to the right or left of either the 3 lines, or at least the phone and email (so the second and third line). Whenever I try to use wrapfig package two things happen. The package is said to be detected, but the command cannot be identified. And my picture gets placed at the end of the document regardless of what I do.

I am compiling with XeLateX and using TeXstudio.

Edit: Basically what happens at the moment is this: [image: Current predicament]. What I'd love to do is this: [image: desired outcome]

Comment: you might want to look into `moderncv`-class for resumees. It is more directed to create "easy-on-the-eyes" CVs

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the requested formats.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, final]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=12.0}\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont\scshape{John Doe }} \hfill 1 of 2\\[2mm]

\raggedright
\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth]{example-image-A}}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\stackunder[1.5mm]{\Large\so{{\Large\Letter} email@server.com}}
{\large\so{{\Large\Telefon} (55) 55-5555-5555}}

\hfill

\section{Education}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and here is the other format:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, final]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=12.0}\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont\scshape{John Doe }} \hfill 1 of 2\\[2mm]

\raggedright
\def\stackalignment{l}
\stackon[1.5mm]
{\large\so{{\Large\Telefon} (55) 55-5555-5555}}
{\Large\so{{\Large\Letter} email@server.com}}
\hfil
\smash{\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{example-image-A}}
\hfill

\section{Education}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]